# how to make a option mandatory/read-only in multiSelect dropdown checklist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multi-select

I am using [jQuery MultiSelect plugin](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/). I have a requirement like -
Make the English language selected by default and English cannot be removed by user.

I have tried like (it is making the English always checked but value is removed) :

JQUERY:

```
jQuery("#language").multiSelect({
    oneOrMoreSelected: '*',
    selectAll: false,
    noneSelected: 'Check some languages!'
}, function(objCheckbox) {
    if (jQuery(objCheckbox).val() == "English") {
        jQuery(objCheckbox).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});​
```

HTML:

```
<select id="language" name="language" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px;">
    <option value="English" selected="selected">English</option>
    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spainish</option>
    <option value="Urdu">Urdu</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
</select>​
```

Here is the [jsfiddle representation](http://jsfiddle.net/VEZMR/1/) if it helps. Thanks for your time.

Comment: hi @Kyle , the `English` option is always checked. This is fine. but it disappears from the comma-separated representation when I click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the plugin you are using does not enable you to do this, but with minor changes to the plugin you can achieve this behavior easily,

1. download the source code of the plugin from http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/jquery.multiSelect.js and save it in your project's library
2. load the locally saved file to you project using `<script src="..THE FILE PATH..."></script>`
3. replace line no. 73 with `var html = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + id + '[]" value="' + option.value + '"' + (option.disabled?' disabled="disabled"':'');`
4. replace line no. 442 with: `suboptions.push({ text: $(this).html(), value: $(this).val(), selected: $(this).attr('selected'),disabled: $(this).is(":disabled") });`
5. replace line no 449 with: `options.push({ text: $(this).html(), value: $(this).val(), selected: $(this).attr('selected'),disabled: $(this).is(":disabled") });`
6. in your html code - add `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the `option` you want to disable
7. you are done

no need for callback function with this implementation

this is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KGUmR/
(i added the minified source of the edited plugin because I didn't want to host it - look at the bottom of the Javascript square for the plugin use)

Comment: That's called a real hacking ! Loving it... :) thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

http://jsfiddle.net/zorro/VEZMR/9/